# Choosing the right file system for Windows and macOS

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, nfs

I currently store my files (images, documents, ...) on a server at home and access them from my Windows PC via a network share with NFS. Since some time ago I also have a Mac. From my Mac I also can access the files either via NFS/SMB or via AFP.

But now I come up to a problem: If I access files on my server from my Mac it creates some files like `._[Name of file]` and `.DS_Store`. I know that this files are created automatically  to store some additional infos / attributes about the files and folder and aren't shown on the Mac itself.

But if I access my server from my Windows PC again I can see all these files. Apart from that this behaviour is really annoying it has some further disadvantages: e. g. if I create a file via Mac and delete it from my Windows PC the `._[Name of file]` file is preserved if I doesn't delete it explicitly.

Is there any soultion for this behaviour? What is the "correct" usage when using Windows and Mac to access the same files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn off the creation of `.DS_Store` files on the Mac
by executing the following commands in Terminal:

For USB drives :

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteUSBStores -bool true
```

For Network drives :

```
 defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true
```

You need to reboot the Mac for this to take effect.

To re-enable the creation of these files, use the same commands
with `false`, and reboot.

Note: The change is per-user.

---

To avoid completely both `.DS_Store` and the resource forks
that are named `._[Name of file]`, you could use
[BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/):

> BlueHarvest automatically removes .DS_Store and ._ AppleDouble files from your USB keys, SD cards, music players, file servers or any non Mac disk. BlueHarvest removes these items as they’re created or modified so you’ll always be metadata free without you needing to lift a finger.

This utility used to be donationware, but is now trialware at
$14.95 for three Macs for personal use.

Of course, you may also avoid those files by not using Finder.

Comment: But will does setting also stop the creation of the files `._[Name of file]`?

Comment: @BenjaminJ.: I expanded my answer.

Comment: Yup, Blue Harvest - the only manageable way to do this. You can kill .DS_Store but you can't kill anything else from command line; short of stripping it all manually periodically. [You will, of course, lose the metadata doing this, same as copying windows files with alternate data streams.]

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks for your response. But is this really the "right" way to manage folder and files which should be accessed by Windows and macOS? Maybe, is there a way to have a APFS / HFS+ partition on my server (server with Debian 11 and full root access) and then access this from my Mac and Windows. In this case the `._` files shouldn't exists because the data can be stored on the partition itself. Is there any solution in this way?

Comment: Windows is very bad on support for APFS/HFS+, as the Mac isn't perfect for NTFS. For a file-system that is well-supported by both, you need to use FAT32. Finder might not add metadata for this old format (but I have no way of checking).

Comment: @harrymc:  Can you tell something about the support for APFS/HFS+ on Linux/Debian?

Comment: It would be better to start a new post for this.